# Remove custom body class from pages with a specific category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying yo Remove custom body class from pages with a specific category in WordPress.

Here is the code below I am trying to make to work. However, it does not.

```
   function remove_body_class($wp_classes) { 
    if ( is_category ('places') ) :
    foreach ( $wp_classes as $key=>$value ) {
       if ( $value =='my_class' ) unset( $wp_classes[ $key ] );}
    endig;
return $wp_classes; 
}  add_filter( 'body_class', 'remove_body_class');
```

It works when I remove class from  all pages without using "i**f ( is_category ('places') ) :**"

But I can't make it work only for specific category/posts.

Could you tell me if I do something wrong? I would highly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be help for you.

// Removes a class from the body_class array.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    if ( isset( $classes['your-class-name'] ) ) {
        unset( $classes['your-class-name'] );
    }
    return $classes;
} );
```

Comment: Hi,  thank you! 

And what to do if I want to remove body class only from a specific category?

Answer (score 0):

```
// 34 is your category id
if (is_category('34')) 
{
    add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
        if ( isset( $classes['your-class-name'] ) ) {
            unset( $classes['your-class-name'] );
        }
        return $classes;
    } );

}
// When the archive page for Category 34 is being displayed.
```

Comment: Why did you post another answer instead of editing your first one?

Answer (score 0):

Define *$cat_id* to the category ID and change "your-class-name" to the name of the class you want removed:

```
if ( is_category($cat_id) ) {
    add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
        if ( null !== array_search( 'your-class-name', $classes) ) {
            unset( $classes[ array_search( 'your-class-name', $classes) ] );
        }

        return $classes;
    } );
}
```